# Do we want new challenges auto posted in chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat, rss

Our chatroom [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) currently has 3 [message feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?tab=feeds). For example, when there is a new [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/) post, it is automatically posted in chat.

Do we want to have [new questions from the main page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) be a new feed?

(Note that feeds are not the same as chatbots per se. Anyone owner of a chatroom can add [RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stackexchange-and-stac) to it; SE chat specifically supports the feature.)

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged [tag:feature-request] or similar?

Comment: @AlexA. I added it but we're not technically asking for a new feature so I'm not sure it's entirely applicable.

Comment: Seems like a new feature to me...

Comment: For those that don't know, we used to have a bot that did this (and a bit more). See [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1177/14215) for info, but the takeaway is that we had this and got rid of it once. Opinions may have changed in the meantime, but I think the discussion is lacking if nobody points it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes

We should add posts to the main page to our chat feeds.

**Reasons**

- People in chat will be aware of new challenges more readily
- People who join chat a while after the challenge is posted will also be informed of the recently posted challenge
- (add more if desired)

Answer (score -4):

## Yes, as an overlay feed

We should add posts to the main page as a feed, but using an overlay feed instead of a chatbot. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUAf0.png)

**Pros**

- People in chat will be aware of new challenges more readily.
- Less obtrusive than a chatbot.
- (add more if desired)

**Cons**

- Overlay feeds do not stay in chat history and can't be linked or referred back to
- (add more if desired)

Answer (score -5):

## No

We should **not** add posts to the main page to our chat feeds.

**Reasons**

- They will clog chat
- (add more if desired)

Comment: Provided this only posts *new* questions (and not every time a question has activity), then we don't have enough questions to clog chat.

Comment: @trichoplax Most definitely I'm only talking about new questions. (I'm not sure if activity can be auto posted.)