# Do we want XKCD autposted in chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat, rss

[El'endia Starman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12914/elendia-starman), a [moderator](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/58/elendia-starman), but not a [PPCG moderator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), has [recently added](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24416667#24416667) an [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/) RSS feed to our chatroom [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), apparently based on [the suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24416208#24416208) of one other user.

I am [vehemently against](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24418068#24418068) this addition to our [list of feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?tab=feeds) for a number of reasons:

1. It was done non-democratically, unlike other [feed suggestions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5247/26997). One user suggested it and another user immediately added it with no additional discussion.
2. It was done by [a PPCG user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12914/elendia-starman) with sub 1000 rep. Yes they are a mod, but not on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf.
3. XKCD has no specific association or relation to PPCG or code golf or Stack Overflow. Their topics overlap, but the same could be said for dozens of webcomics.
4. Anyone who actually wants to read XKCD will probably continue to do so at its [main site](http://xkcd.com). There's no need for us to be an XKCD mirror. It will always be possible for users to post particularly appropriate comics in chat for discussion.

**Do we want every single future XKCD comic autoposted in chat?**

Comment: Being the person who suggested this, I do feel that El'endia was rather rash in his/her's implementation.

Comment: My apologies. I'll not make this mistake again in the future.

Answer (score 27):

## No

We should remove the XKCD feed from The Nineteenth Byte.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Comment: If a comic is relevant, it is going to be linked anyway. Autoposting this specific comic is "not as bad", but not doing it is better.

Answer (score -8):

## Yes

Let's keep the XKCD feed in The Nineteenth Byte.

Comment: -1 from me (can't vote)